# Can I create classes from schema/sql/and sql queries in mybatis?

Tags: orm, schema, mybatis, creation

I am more a database person than OO (even that I can do). So, I have a database as sql strings, and a lot of queries (also of course the content). I do not, actually, want to "type that down" to an OO model (e.g. `class Person int id get/set(int id)` etc) - SQL is so quick instead of that. It is a client requirement to use ORM.

Is there a tool that can do that for me? (I would rather write my own parser to do that procedure than to "code" that all). Also, if mybatis can't do it, is there another ORM software that can do so? (any ORM software will do, actually, just that mybatis is said to be lightweight and sql-similar).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Mybatis generator plugin](http://mybatis.github.io/generator/index.html) pretty bit simple.

If you are using maven in your project here is basic plugin configuration

```
<pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.3.2,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>generate</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
                <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configurationFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/kp-mybatis-generator.xml</configurationFile>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Generate MyBatis Artifacts</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

And the generator xml configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE generatorConfiguration
  PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD MyBatis Generator Configuration 1.0//EN"
  "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-generator-config_1_0.dtd">
<generatorConfiguration>

    <classPathEntry location="C:\down\ojdbc6.jar" />

    <context id="kpOracleGens" targetRuntime="MyBatis3Simple">
        <jdbcConnection driverClass="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            connectionURL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:KPORACLE" userId="******"
            password="******">
        </jdbcConnection>

        <javaModelGenerator targetPackage="com.kp.swasthik.db.domain"
            targetProject="MAVEN">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="false" />
            <property name="trimStrings" value="false" />
        </javaModelGenerator>

        <sqlMapGenerator targetPackage="com.kp.swasthik.db.persistence"
            targetProject="MAVEN">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="false" />
        </sqlMapGenerator>

        <javaClientGenerator type="XMLMAPPER"
            targetPackage="com.kp.swasthik.db.mapper" targetProject="MAVEN"
            implementationPackage="com.kp.swasthik.db.service">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="true" />
        </javaClientGenerator>

        <table tableName="%KPC%" catalog="*" schema="kprasad">
            <property name="useActualColumnNames" value="true" />
        </table>
        <table tableName="FOO" catalog="*" schema="kprasad">
            <property name="useActualColumnNames" value="true" />
        </table>
    </context>
</generatorConfiguration>
```